# Java Game Dev: Trying to Separate World and Renderer

Tags: java, oop, frameworks

I'm developing a small game in Java and I have run into a problem deciding how to abstract my game world from the framework I'm using.

As I have it now I have a class called `World` that keeps track of all of the different objects in the world and updates them according to the game rules. Then I have three basic object classes `Person`, `Obstacle`, and `Item`. Each object has different "types" which are represented by a member variable. All of the object classes are extended from the class `GameObject`.

As I have it now the `World` and object classes are separate from the framework that renders the game and etc. The class `Game` both tells the world to update and renders the world and the objects in the world.

The problem is that I render the objects with the three methods `drawPersons()`, `drawObstacles()` and `drawItems()` which is fine because I already wrote the code and I won't be adding any more object classes. The real problem is rendering the different "types" of each object class. As I have it now the draw methods draw the items by checking the variable `object.type` then there's a switch statement which picks the appropriate bitmap to draw.

I want to simplify this so I don't have to add to the switch statement every time I add a new "type" to the `Item` class for example. The only way I can think to do this is to have the objects store what bitmap they should be rendered as when they are constructed and have their item.type variable set. This way I could remove the switch statements from the `drawItems()` method. In addition I could also give each object class a draw() method blah blah blah but the reason I don't want to do this is because it ruins the separation I have from the renderer/framework and the imaginary game world.

I'm not sure what to do, on one hand I know it's a bad idea to be using switch statements like I currently am but on the other I know it's better design to have my `World` and object classes independent from the framework so if I wanted to I could slap it into a new framework or whatever down the line.

Is there a way I can have both?

Comment: Just as a side note: you might get more specific help here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, is there a way to move this question there or do I just repost the question?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can more the question, but I'm sure a moderator can. We could flag it for moderator attention to make them move it if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use composition, i.e. your entities contain several components that have different purposes. For example, there might be a rendering component, a physics component, an ai component etc.

The world would manage the entities in general and the subsystems would then query the entities for the correct components. Thus if the renderer wants to render an entity it queries it for the rendering component and maybe a position component and uses the data those provide to render the entity.

In that case the rendering component might contain data like texture/bitmap, shape, material etc.

For more information you might want to look into [entity systems](http://entity-systems.wikidot.com/).

Comment: Your link brought me to [this article](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/) and I'm curious how I would pull this off in Java specifically.

Comment: @StickFigs Have a look at the opensource implementations sections of the link I posted. The author has an example Java implementation there (actually there are two: ES Alpha and ES Beta). Here's the link to the ES Beta repo for convenience: https://github.com/adamgit/Entity-System-RDBMS-Beta--Java-

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment anymore, here's a correction: Have a look at the "ES approaches" link in the first section of the article I linked :)

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be an issue to store an image object in each of your drawable objects. Storing an image doesn't disrupt the way your rendering loops function. Sometimes over-abstraction can be cumbersome if it's not needed. I see nothing wrong with storing images in objects. Switch statements quickly become very inefficient once you begin to add more drawable objects to your game. Think of games with hundreds of drawable objects. Pointers require little space and speed up your code in the long run.

Comment: I really appreciate your viewpoint on sacrificing abstraction for simplicity and performance. If I am unable to find an alternative solution I will most likely go with this.

Comment: Abstraction might best serve you in a highly object-oriented environment with lots of data overlap. Also think of code modularity. Abstraction can come in many forms. By abstracting draw() methods out of your drawable objects, you are sacrificing the flexibility of your World's render loop. There might be more viable solutions to this, but a switch() statement is definitely *not* the way to approach it. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could investigate the [Visitor pattern](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?VisitorPattern). Your game world objects take a visitor that literate through them performing some operation: in this case the operation is drawing. Logic for choosing different implementations based on what the game object is gets kept on the visitor side.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could wrap your classes using the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

A Decorator contains a `GameObject` instance and will also implement the `GameObject` functions by calling the methods on the original instance.

When you are subclassing GameObject in such a way, you can also make the decorators implement a `Renderable` interface with a `draw()` method.

Answer (score 1):

---

my suggest to you is to use bitmap atlasing i.e all you images in one big image , and then make an abstract method in your GameObject class that returns the regions that a game object has in the atlas.

like this

```
public abstract class GameObject{

...
...
..

public abstract TextureRegion getGameObjectTextureRegion();
...
..
}
```

and in each class that extends GameObject store a instance variable like this

```
public class Person extends GameObject{
....
....
...
public static final TextureRegion person_region = new TextureRegion(top,left,height,width);
...
...
public TextureRegion getGameObjectTextureRegion(){
return person_region;
}
```

then store all your game objects in array or `ArrayList`
like this

```
ArrayList<GameObject> game_objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();
//add items to it 
game_objects.add(new Person());
gmae_objects.add(...);
```

and in your draw method  loop the game_objects list and call getGameObjectTextureRegion

```
for(GameObject item : game_objects)
{
TextureRegion region = item.getGameObjectTextureRegion();
// then pass them with the game object position to your rendering method 
...


}
```

note: TextureRegion looks like this

```
public class TextureRegion{

float top;
float left;
float width;
float height;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea in theory but unfortunately I'm prone to changing graphical assets frequently and my workflow isn't sophisticated enough to automatically handle all the shifting around I would need to do with the atlas

Answer (score 0):

I like Thomas's "entity systems" answer. But I was thinking of a different approach myself. I will try to present it as abstractly as possible as I'm not very familiar with Java.

You could have some kind of a 'resources' variable that stores pairs of object_type:data which contains the required resources for each type of objects you intend to insert in your world. The 'resources' variable can be a list of animations or any other common resources.

To be more concrete, let me give you an example in Python (since this is what I know best). Shouldn't be a problem to apply the same in Java or virtually any other language for that matter. In Python, I would create a dictionary variable that looks like this:

```
{
Person1:["person1.bmp", "person1_alternative1.bmp", "person1_whatever.wmv"],
Person2:["person2.bmp", "person2_alternative1.bmp", "person2_whatever.wmv"],
Obstacle1:["Obstacle1.bmp", "Obstacle1_alternative1.bmp", "Obstacle1_whatever.xyz"],
Obstacle1:["Item1.bmp", "Item1_alternative1.bmp", "Item1_whatever.xyz"]
}
```

... and so on

You could extend that furthermore as you see fit; Add other kinds of resources, perhaps objects coordinates, dimensions or whatever.. For example

```
{
person1:{basic_animation:"person1.bmp", alt_animation:"person1_alternative1.bmp", sfx1:"person1_whatever.wmv"},
person2:{basic_animation:"person2.bmp", alt_animation:"person2_alternative1.bmp", sfx1:"person2_whatever.wmv"},
obstacle1:{basic_animation:"obstacle1.bmp", alt_animation:"obstacle1_alternative1.bmp", res1:"obstacle1_whatever.xyz"},
item1:{basic_animation:"item1.bmp", alt_animation:"item1_alternative1.bmp", sfx1:"item1_whatever.wmv"}
}
```

The syntax and is probably different in Java, but you get the general idea. I'm not sure how Java handles key:value kind of variables, I assume it has some class for this. If not, you can always make your own.

This big 'resources' variable can be part of your game class and be initialized and populated with relevant data when you you instance the game class. It can even be stored somewhere else if you prefer grouping all your constants in a separate place/module/whatever (which I do!). Then you can unify those drawPersons(), drawObstacles() and drawItems() into a single draw() function that checks 'object.type' for each 'object' and looks it up in 'resources' to get its relevant data.

Now I don't know about performance and other factors, probably it needs some optimization from someone cleverer!

Comment: Wow! I've just realized how old the question is :|